# Como alterar chave de um array PHP

Tags: php, array, laravel

Estou precisando alterar a chave de uma array

```
$task=array('Title' => 'Test', 'Description' => 'Description test')
```

Preciso alterar o nome da key **Description**

Existe alguma forma?

Estou trabalhando com o framework Laravel

Comment: Respondi mas saliento que isso é básico de PHP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parece simples, mas não é tão trivial assim.

A resposta à sua pergunta é: **não é possível**. Dito isso você me perguntaria "como não é possível se as outras respostas mostraram como fazer?" e eu responderia "eles mentiram (no mínimo omitiram) para você".

O PHP, por decisão interna, resolveu definir uma estrutura "genérica" para trabalhar com quase todas as outras estruturas de dados, tanto que não é difícil você ler que PHP é orientado a *array* - quase tudo é *array* no PHP. Bem como a própria [documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) traz:

> Um *array* no PHP é na verdade um mapa ordenado. Um mapa é um tipo que relaciona valores a chaves. Este tipo é otimizado para várias usos diferentes: ele pode ser tratado como um *array*, uma lista (vetor), *hashtable* (que é uma implementação de mapa), dicionário, coleção, pilha, fila e provavelmente mais.

Talvez possa ter passado-lhe despercebido, mas a definição começa com o trecho mais importante:

> Um array no PHP é na verdade um mapa [...] que relaciona valores a chaves.

E você não consegue **alterar** a chave de um mapa. O que você consegue é copiar o valor de uma chave, criando uma nova e excluindo a antiga, mas isso não é alterar. Foi isso que a resposta do [Lucas Azambuja](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333556/5878) fez e é a forma mais prática de se obter o resultado desejado. Você conseguiria ainda abstrair isso para uma função:

```
function array_replace_key(&$arr, $old, $new, $overwrite = true): bool {
    if (isset($arr[$new]) and !$overwrite) {
        return false;
    }

    $arr[$new] = $arr[$old];
    unset($arr[$old]);

    return true;
}
```

<sup>Veja functionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ZigzagRectangularAccess) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/a8ApcS)</sup>

Para "substituir" a chave `description` por `descrição`, por exemplo, bastaria fazer `array_replace_key($task, 'description', 'descrição')`. Caso a chave `descrição` já existir no *array* ele será sobrescrito; se esse não for o comportamento desejado, você pode passar o último argumento como falso que o valor existente será mantido inalterado, `array_replace_key($task, 'description', 'descrição', false)`. A função retornará um booleano indicando se houve ou não a "substituição" da chave.

Vale lembrar que como é feita a cópia do valor de uma chave para outra, dependendo do que é esse valor, poderá ter problemas com memória, pois durante a execução da função você terá dois objetos iguais.

A solução com `array_merge` tende a ser ruim na maioria dos casos, pois além de manter 3 cópias do seu objeto em memória (uma no objeto original, outra no parâmetro da função e a terceira no novo *array* a ser mesclado), fará uma operação que é diretamente dependente do tamanho do *array* (no mínimo O(N)). Isso significa que se você possuir um *array* com milhares de valores, a operação irá demorar mais, mesmo que a intenção seja apenas alterar uma chave.

Quanto à solução utilizando funções definidas pelo Laravel eu não sei avaliar. Não sei se as funções fazem apenas o que prometem e de que forma fazem, mas inicialmente acho desnecessário utilizar funções de um framework para tal. Se existirem vantagens em utilizá-las talvez o [Marcos Xavier](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/333575/5878) saberá responder melhor.

Comment: Muito obrigado Anderson, sua resposta foi completa e clara, estou inciando em programação WEB e foi muito bom entender mais sobre esse tipo de manipulação de ARRAY, a explicação sobre memoria foi perfeita... Sempre tinha visto respostas dando essa mesmo função de array, sem a menor explicação, muito obrigado mesmo.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php 

$task=array('Title' => 'Test', 'Description' => 'Description test');
$task['NovoNome'] = $task['Description'];
unset($task['Description']);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No jeito Laravel de fazer. Usei a sintaxe contraída de array $array = ['...']; ( disponível a partir do PHP 5.4 https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php )

```
$task = ['Title' => 'Test', 'Description' => 'Description test'];

//remove a chave Description,equivalente a unset($task['Description'])
array_forget($task, 'Description');
dump($task);

$task = array_add($task,'New Description','New description test');
//add no início do array
$task = array_prepend($task,'First Key','First');
dump($task);
```

Up.
Testado na versão 5.4 e 5.5 do Laravel